# Redirection Link not Updating to Fetch New Information

Tags: acumatica

I added a redirection link to the reference numbers in a grid that link back to receipts. I followed the instructions given in T200 to perform the task, except 
I made the page that opens a popup instead of a new tab. It works for the first reference number I click, but after that it doesn't change the record. Instead the popup displays the record for the first reference number I clicked. Here is my code:

```
    protected void RefNbrReceipt()
    {
        INRegister row = Receipts.Current;

        INReceiptEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INReceiptEntry>();

        graph.receipt.Current = graph.receipt.Search<INRegister.refNbr>(row.RefNbr);

        if (graph.receipt.Current != null)
        {
            throw new PXPopupRedirectException(graph, "Receipt Details");
        }
    }
```

I checked and made sure that the row updates to the selected value (I do have SyncPosition = true on the grid) as well as after the Search that  graph.receipt.Current.RefNbr = row.RefNbr. All of the objects in the code when debugging and stepping through it are set to the correct values they should be. Even though these values are showing correctly, when the popup appears, it still has the incorrect record (the first record fetched).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Current is set correctly?
If not make sure you use DependOnGrid:

```
<px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="RefNbrReceipt" Visible="False" DependOnGrid="grid" CommitChanges="True" /></CallbackCommands>
```

You can also try setting CurrentDocument and Current cache record before opening the graph:

```
INRegister inRegister = graph.receipt.Search<INRegister.refNbr>(row.RefNbr);
graph.receipt.CurrentDocument.Current = inRegister;
graph.Caches[typeof(INRegister)].Current = inRegister;
```

In some scenario with popup windows, you need to issue a refresh command with AutoCallBack-Command and AutoCallBack-Target attributes, you can do that with grid and form containers:

```
<px:PXSmartPanel ID="pnlActivityLog" runat="server" Width="800px" Height="400px" Style="z-index: 108;" Caption="Activity log" CaptionVisible="True" 
                 Key="ActivityLogs" CommandSourceID="ds" CreateOnDemand="False" AutoCallBack-Command="Refresh" AutoCallBack-Target="gridActivityLog">
    <px:PXGrid ID="gridActivityLog" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="100%" BatchUpdate="True" SkinID="Inquire" DataSourceID="ds">
    </px:PXPanel>
</px:PXSmartPanel>
```

Comment: Added the CommitChanges = true line to my ASPX defining the action and added graph.Caches[typeof(INRegiste)].Current = row (since row is the target I want) and that still didn't do it. It feels like when I click on the first entry, it loads new data, but anytime I click on another record there is no reloading of the required data and it just pops open the old screen. Any way to force the popup to reload the data before displaying?

Comment: Can you manually refresh the screen with the refresh button and does it show the good record if you do that?

Comment: Because it is a popup, I do not get the ability to just refresh the popup via the browser (even right clicking and clicking refresh). There isn't  any refresh button on the page itself either (Acumatica refresh button).

Comment: I added that to my code, but it just made my grid disappear. If you'd like, I can send you more pieces of my code if you need. I didn't generate this popup initially using a smart panel, so I'm not sure if that matters for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue PXPopupRedirectException

To solve this I used PXRedirectRequiredException like this:

throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, "Subcontract", true) { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };

This opens up a new browser window and repaints the controls of the calling window.
This is necessary if you have child grids that are depending on the row you click - and if the use 'changes rows' by clicking directly on the link.